# HTTP proxy (caching) for Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: proxy, http, squid, cache

I'm trying to find a good HTTP proxy for personal use (I might want to experiment with the code too.) Other than squid, I found tinyproxy and polipo, but apparently tinyproxy doesn't do caching. Do you know any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing much, there are few caching proxies smaller than squid, its under 1mb, and uses very little memory, provided you don't push it or misconfigure it.

If you want to dissect a proxy, micro-proxy (although non-caching afaik) is like 350 lines of code, so should be easy to follow.

Perhaps if you gave a little more detail as to what you wish to accomplish, i could make a better recommendation.